# Error with sys_refcursor and object type in ORacle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create table s1  (id  number,name varchar2(10));
create table s2 as select * from s1 where 1=2;

insert into s1 values(1,'tri');
insert into s1 values(2,'ran');

create or replace type rt as object
(id  number,name varchar2(10));
CREATE or replace TYPE tt AS TABLE OF rt;

create or replace procedure chk (c_cursor in sys_refcursor) as
sweeper_assigned_t  tt;
begin
 loop
 fetch c_cursor bulk collect into sweeper_assigned_t;
 EXIT WHEN c_cursor%NOTFOUND;
 end loop;
 
  forall i in 1..sweeper_assigned_t.count
    insert into s2 ( id, name)
  values ( sweeper_assigned_t(i).id, sweeper_assigned_t(i).name);
  commit;

end chk;

declare
    c_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
    open c_cur
    for select * from s1 ;
    
    chk( c_cur);
    
end;
```

On execting getting below error:
Error report -
ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match
ORA-06512: at "MTM.CHK", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 7
06504. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match"
*Cause:    Number and/or types of columns in a query does not match declared
return type of a result set  variable, or declared types of two Result
Set variables do not match.
*Action:   Change the program statement or declaration. Verify what query the variable
actually refers to during execution.

Comment: Try to substitute "rt" definition with "create or replace type rt is record
(id  number,name varchar2(10));"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
declare
    c_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
    open c_cur
    for select rt(id,name) from s1 ;
    
    chk( c_cur);
    
end;
/
```

The error you get is because, in your procedure,  you're selecting into a table of objects, but the cursor returns just a number of columns